# How to invoke octave script in unix shell

Tags: shell, scripting, command-line-interface, sh, octave

I have written an octave script file (.m)

If anyone could point me out on how to run octave scripts on unix shell that would be really helpful. I do not want to execute the script by invoking octave program.

I am new to unix and octave.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you planning to run an octave script without running octave? Hint: you can't. But, you can call octave just to run your script: `octave -q script.m` should work with "quiet" mode, no extra garbage dumped by octave.

Comment: @AndrasDeak the same way you invoke scripts from any other language (maybe except Matlab and R). You don't need to actually specify `octave` on the command line if you do it properly.

Comment: Well, @carandraug, the shebang will only tell the shell to invoke octave for you. It's just less transparent, but it's still octave calling running the script.

Comment: @AndrasDeak considering the language and the question, I think this is exactly what the OP meant. Not having to specify it on the command line. Just like you don't have to specify on the command line bash, python, perl, or ruby when calling stuff from `/usr/bin` written on those languages.

Comment: @carandraug I guess you're right. To be fair, I always invoke my scripts explicitly:)

Comment: Thank you so much AndrasDeak :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, of course you can write an Octave program. Like so:

```
$ cat octave_program 
#!/usr/bin/env octave
## Never forget your licence at the top of the files.
1;

function [rv] = main (argv)
  disp ("hello world");
  rv = 0;
  return;
endfunction

main (argv);

$ chmod a+x octave_program # add executable permissions
$ ./octave_program 
hello world
```

There's a couple of things important for an Octave program:

1. the first statement cannot be a function declaration. In all my programs, the first statements are loading of necessary packages. If you don't have packages, it is common to use `1;`
2. a [she-bang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). That's the first line of your program which tells you how to run your program.  If you know where Octave will be installed, you can use `#!/usr/bin/octave` but using `#!/usr/bin/env octave` will be more portable and flexible.
3. your program needs executable permissions