# How to run octave scripts on MacOS?

Tags: macos, octave

Using instruction from the website:
http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X

I installed octave on MacOS X 10.9.5.
The installed apps are in:
/Applications/Octave-cli.app
/Applications/Octave-gui.app

Now, i have a octave script called example.m

```
%file: example.m
print('hello')
```

How can i run this file from the terminal?

```
NOTE:

    open /Applications/Octave-cli.app  # this works fine
    open /Applications/Octave-gui.app  # this freezes the octave program
```

Then i can write and run octave commands interactively.

What i want is:

```
octave myexample.m
```

should give results, as like `python myscript.py` gives.

**UPDATE:**
I uninstalled:
 /Applications/Octave-cli.app and /Applications/Octave-gui.app

Then, i downloaded two apps
    download Octave 4.0.2 with graphical user interface (OS X 10.9+),
    download Octave 4.0.2 with command line interface (OS X 10.9+)

from the website:
http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X
Then, i got Octave.app where i can write and run octave scripts in that graphical interface.

But, i also want to run from command line:

```
octave myexample.m
```

some related links are following:
[How to invoke octave script in unix shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669024/how-to-invoke-octave-script-in-unix-shell)

Comment: A google search for "Run octave scripts in terminal" brings up loads of results. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: @brimstone yes, but non of them worked for me. FYI octave runs fine in my laptop (Ubuntu 15.1), but not in the office desktop (MacOS).

Comment: `octave myexample.m` should work so long as you have the `octave` executable in your `PATH`. Type `which octave` to confirm.

Comment: @PaulR which octave shows octave: Command not found.

Comment: OK - it sounds like you don't have your PATH set up correctly - make sure your `PATH` includes whichever directory your `octave` executable resides in - on my OS X installation I see it in `/usr/local/bin` but I expect yours may be in e.g. `/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin`.

Comment: ls /usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin shows these things: octave   octave-cli  octave-config
octave-3.8.0  octave-cli-3.8.0 octave-config-3.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install Xcode and and any of the package managers mentioned (if in doubt: pick homebrew) on the [page](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X) you referenced already ?

If not, the solution is to go there.

Additional ref: http://wiki.octave.org/Create_a_MacOS_X_App_Bundle_Using_Homebrew

Comment: I removed previous cli and gui apps. then reinstalled. Now i can see Octave.app. it has graphical interface and i can write and run there. but i also like to run from command line such as octave myexample.m.

Comment: "then reinstalled" : Exactly how  ? Via homebrew ?  E.g.: https://adampash.com/how-to-install-octave/

Comment: just double clicking installed the programs. But still it works sometimes and freezes sometimes.

Answer (score 7):

After installing the GUI 4.0.3 on macOS, you can use this path to CLI:

```
/Applications/Octave.app/Contents/Resources/usr/bin/octave-cli
```

This is an alias to:

```
/Applications/Octave.app/Contents/Resources/usr/Cellar/octave/4.0.3/bin/octave-cli-4.0.3
```

But running the first is probably up version safe.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this a thousand time. Was quick (unlike the install_octave.sh in their tutorial) and it works flawlessly.